How to access the camera in a captive portal where camera permissions are denied?
I'm developing a web application that runs in a captive portal, and my application needs to access the device's camera. However, I'm encountering an issue where the captive portal denies camera permissions, preventing my application from opening the camera.
I've tried the following:

Ensuring my application is served over HTTPS.

Despite these efforts, the camera permissions are still blocked by the captive portal. Is there a way to resolve this issue so that my application can access the camera in the captive portal environment?
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
